# Handling case when ui-select-choices returns 0 items in angular-iu / ui-select component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, ui-select

There's a case when user types something in ui-select and doesn't find anything - the result array is empty.

I want to handle this case & show something like "Create New".

This item should be visible only when nothing is found after search.

When user clicks this item some custom handler should run, simple alert() for example.

Could you help me how to do that?